# How can I get the scale value from the scaleControl of Google maps api v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, scale

I'm using google maps API v3.
I want to get the scale value from the scaleControl.

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post an image,here is an illustrate.

```
|  200m  | 
------------------
| 1000ft         |
```

My english is poor, hope to make myself clear.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

fomula:  Math.pow(2,21-map.getZoom())*distance;
// may useful for you.

Comment: What is distance? And what does 21 mean,the maximum zoom level?